# check an attribute set or not in input tag using dojo or javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

How to check an attribute set or not in input tag using dojo or javascript

For example: An input tag may have value attribute and not

```
<input type="text" style="width:54%" name="entertask">
```

or

```
<input type="text" style="width:54%" name="entertask" value="new">
```

How I can check this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dojo.hasAttr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/hasAttr.html).

Comment: dojo.hasAttr('value') will ALWAYS return true for an input, no matter whether or not the value was actually provided as an attribute.

Comment: Agreed, but the question was not about the value attribute specifically, although the example shown in the question shows that particular attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like this ?

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" style="width:54%" name="entertask" value="new"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var inputElement = dojo.byId("myInput");
    var hasValueAttribute = dojo.attr(inputElement, "value") != '' ;
    console.log(hasValueAttribute);
</script>
```

Comment: I avoided 'id' intentionally to avoid id collision

Comment: or... dojo.hasAttr(inputElement, "value");

Answer (score 0):

using javascript, you can do it like

```
document.getElementsByName("entertask")[0].getAttribute("value");
```

if the `attribute` is not present, it will return `null`.

check fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4QzeW/1/

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this from browser console

function $(ele){
      `if (document.getElementById(ele)!== null)`
         `return document.getElementById(ele);`
}

```
console.log ($('input_element').hasAttribute('attribute_name') === true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with the current versions of IE, FF, Chrome (you will need to assign an id to your input tag):

```
function attributeExists(id, attr)
{
  var attr = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute(attr);
  return !(attr == null || attr.length == 0);
}
```